# Magento 2 : How to save database column value in a variable

Tags: magento2, php, database, sql

Following is my table structure
[image]

How to save the 'value' column in a variable.
I used following code:

```
$this->_resources = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');   
    $connection= $this->_resources->getConnection();
    $tableName = $this->_resources->getTableName('customer_entity_varchar');
    $sql2 = "SELECT value FROM customer_entity_varchar WHERE `entity_id`='$suser_id'";
    $result1 = $connection->fetchall($sql2);
    return $result;
```

Answer (score 2):

> In your model create this file:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

class Item extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{     

protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Item');
}  

public function getPhonenumber($suser_id)
{
    $select = $this->_getResource()->getConnection()->select()->from($this->_getResource()->getTable('customer_entity_varchar'), ['phone'=>'value'])
    ->where('entity_id = ?', $suser_id);
    $data = $this->_getResource()->getConnection()
      ->fetchAll($select);
      return $data;
}   

}
```

Now change the Class name **Item** according to your model name and the resourcemodel name.
Please let me know if need further assistance.